# Emas on windows gives a warning when loading theme (can run Lisp code)

Tags: microsoft-windows

I am relatively new to running Emacs on Windows.
And I keep getting this warning / question while booting Emacs:
`Loading a theme can run Lisp code. Really load?` (see image below)

Can I somehow do so this warning does not constantly come?

[image]

Comment: `(setq custom-safe-themes t)` may help

Comment: yup that solved the issue thank you so much. Maybe you could create at as an awesome so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme you mentioned in the question is considered unsafe by Emacs because

> Loading a theme can run Lisp code.

So just put

```lisp
(setq custom-safe-themes t)
```

into your settings file.

This variable's docstring says:

> If the value is t, Emacs **treats all themes as safe**.

---

Personally, I see no need to set it to any other value because I'm probably too lazy to look at the source code of a theme to determine whether it is safe, and my answer to '*Really load?*' is almost always yes.